# sqlite command in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Here I am using Sqlite Database for my Application, and my Database Table contains the column keyjson and values in rows  are like below

```
{"filename":"21-01-3-02","label":""}
{"filename":"02-C-4-1","label":"17"}
{"filename":"14-L-3-2","label":"Nord  Est"}
{"filename":"02-Z-5-1NouvelleIndustrieSectionValton","label":"1810"}
```

json data sas string

now I need to particular string that like

```
02
1
2
1NouvelleIndustrieSectionValton
```

from that particular column .

can anyone know the query for it,
Please replay me 
&regards

Comment: If your data is stored as JSON in the database then you need to run it through NSJSONSerialization to parse it (after fetching a row from the DB) and then you'd have to use the NSString function `componentsSeparatedByString` to separate the "filename" string into the pieces you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without SQLite query. First, convert your JSON to a `NSMutableArray` :

```
NSData *data = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Then you can parse it easily as follow :

```
NSMutableArray *finalResult = [NSMutableArray array];
NSString *filename;
for (id e in res){
    filename = [e objectForKey:@"filename"];
    [finalResult addObject:[[filename componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject]];
}
// Here we go, finalResult contains the values you want
```

The problem is that your "JSON" is not valid JSON. It should look like this if you want it works :

```
[
    {
        "filename": "21-01-3-02",
        "label": ""
    },
    {
        "filename": "02-C-4-1",
        "label": "17"
    },
    {
        "filename": "14-L-3-2",
        "label": "Nord  Est"
    },
    {
        "filename": "02-Z-5-1NouvelleIndustrieSectionValton",
        "label": "1810"
    }
]
```

Comment: But it Time Consumption, and I know this process.But I Know The actual Quiry for the above